# Using jQuery live with context

Tags: jquery

I wrote a plugin for jQuery but now my users are asking for the ability to run my plugin on various elements on the same page so I'm trying to rewrite it a bit.

I'm having issues with my events.

here is what was working.

```
$(".jTagLabels label").live('mouseenter',function(){
    $("#"+$(this).attr('rel')).css('opacity',1).find("span").show();
    $(".jTagDeleteTag").show();
});
```

Now I'm trying to register this event on specific context but It's not working.

```
$(".jTagLabels label",container).live('mouseenter',function(){
    $("#"+$(this).attr('rel')).css('opacity',1).find("span").show();
    $(".jTagDeleteTag",container).show();
});
```

console.log(container) returns the right dom element...

It may be important to say that when I setup the event there is no jTagLabels created and that's why I'm using the live() function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), it's a lot cleaner and that's what it was made for, even though the resulting code could be the same.

Also depending on your code context, your `container` variable is likely to lose its value between binding the event and triggering it.

```
$(container).delegate(".jTagLabels label",'mouseenter',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#"+$this.attr('rel')).css('opacity',1).find("span").show();

    // There should be an easier way to find your container,
    // like .closest('.someclass')
    $this.parent().parent().find('.jTagDeleteTag').show();
});
```